# Prove $\tanh x=\frac{\sinh(2x)}{1+\cosh(2x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

**Question**

> Prove $\tanh x=\frac{\sinh(2x)}{1+\cosh(2x)}$

My work:

$$\frac{\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2}}{1+\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{2}}$$

Simplifies down to $$\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$$

But then I do not know what to do from there

Comment: Are you aware of the identity $\tan\frac{t}{2}=\frac{\sin t}{1+\cos t}$? If so, just replace $t$ with $2ix$ and profit :D

Comment: It is not sin/cos/tan, but sinh/cosh/tanh @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @YujieZha: they are called hyperbolic trigonometric functions also because $\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$ and $\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x)$.

Comment: It is one of the classical forms for $\tanh x$!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ah, thanks. Yea, I know they are hyperbolic, but I did not see you later part of the comment (the 2ix part, was reading from a phone) nice comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing numerator and denominator by $e^x$ gives
$$ \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1} \frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}} = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}\frac{2}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} = \frac{\sinh{x}}{\cosh{x}}=\tanh{x}. $$